# Django: Why am i getting the An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block

Tags: django, django-models

So i've been cracking on this issue for days now and i do not seem to get closer to a fix.

I currently have two models. A PurchaseOrder (PO) model and a PurchaseOrderLine (POL) model. The POL models has a foreignkey to PO.

I upload a CSV and using pandas i'm reading through each line of the csv and parsing it accordingly. First it tries to do an PO.objects.get_or_create() based on the values in the row.

Using that created PO, i do some logic and basically end up creating a POL instance that i want to link to the earlier mentioned PO instance.

However, when creating the POL, i get a:

> TransactionManagementError
> An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.

And i do not understand why that is. I have similar logic in my code elsewhere, for example creating a Order and then adding OrderLines to that Order. Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

See below all code relevant (i removed some logic about settings values etc).
The error is thrown at the final block where the POL is created using the get_or_create().

```
@classmethod
def parse_purchase_order_from_csv(cls, purchase_file, store_id, supplier_id=0, field_mapping='', invoice_number='', create_product=False, scrape=False):
    # open the CSV file
    import pandas as pd

    #Some parsing of data here

    # remove empty lines
    df = df.dropna(how='all')
    lines = len(df)
    # open each row
    for row in df.itertuples():
        # Create Purchase Order.
        status = {
            'total_lines': lines,
            'lines_processed': 1,
            'lines_success': 0,
            'error_lines': []
        }

        # Some parsing

        po, po_created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
            internal_id=internal_id,
            supplier=supplier,
            store_id=store_id,
            defaults={
                'purchase_date': purchase_date,
                'status': status
            }
        )
        
        if po.completed:
            # already handled and closed
            continue

        # Here was some logic linking the POL to a product.

        if product:
            pol, pol_created = po.purchaseorderline_set.get_or_create(
                label=label,
                ean=row[ean_col + 1],
                purchase_order=po,
                defaults={
                    'amount': row[quantity_col + 1],
                    'label': label,
                    'product': product,
                    'ean': row[ean_col + 1],
                }
            )
            pol.save()
        else:
            pol, pol_created = po.purchaseorderline_set.get_or_create(
                label=label,
                ean=row[ean_col + 1],
                purchase_order=po,
                defaults={
                    'amount': row[quantity_col + 1],
                    'label': label,
                    'ean': row[ean_col + 1],
                }
            )
            pol.save()

        po.status['lines_success'] += 1
        po.save()
```